# Enter \n newline character in embedded postscript via pstricks

Tags: pstricks, postscript

I want to be able to print neat debugging messages through pstricks/postscript. 
In the code below, how do I make the gs interpreter display a new line?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)(1,1)
\pstVerb{
(This is a debug string.) print
(\n I want to print the next debug string in a new line.) print
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

In other words, how do I execute the postscript code

```
(\n) print
```

through pstricks?

Thanks!

P.S. I need to debug my 3d library. It's already working and can do cool stuff such as the picture below (including the picture 'cause a picture, even if irrelevant, doesn't hurt :)

[image: an irrelevant but cool picture - two linked moebius bands. No lightning effects yet.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)(1,1)
\pstVerb{
(This is a debug string.) print
(\string\n I want to print the next debug string in a new line.) print
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

```
$ ps2pdf file.ps
This is a debug string.
I want to print the next debug string in a new line.
```